# Different background colors between browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, colors, background

I am using a the colour #f9f9f9 for a div background on my website, next to a pure white div. This colour is too close to white for a lot of laptops and computers to distinguish. (I am using a Mac which is fine)

How can I implement a different colour for IE users? So it is #f9f9f9 in safari, but #EEEEEE in IE

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CSS Hacks:

This will be applied to Chrome and Safari

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .className {background-color:#f9f9f9;}
}
```

For IE - Add these two Styles also along with the default background style. So you rclass will look like this

```
.className
{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    background-color: #eeeeee\0/IE8+9;
    background-color: #eeeeee\9;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response! But I only want to change the css property if it's being viewed in IE

Comment: Modified the answer, please check.